# Getting the symbols of kernel32

Tags: c++, windows, kernel32, symbol-server

Is the Symbol Server the only way to get the symbols of kernel32.dll in C++/Windows?
thanks:)

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but you can also download symbol packages from Microsoft website: http://goo.gl/yFzRh

Comment: It might not be the only way, but it's often the best

Comment: @DReJ: Please don't post shortened URLs. The commenting system will automatically truncate them if they're particularly long; this isn't Twitter. It's nice to know what you're clicking on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could download symbol packages too.  Start point [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/symbolpkg.mspx).